# Do not understand this syntax error

Tags: python, json

I am running a Python program and it keeps throwing me this error I do not understand. The syntax is exactly how it is written in the `json`  documentation:

```
    json.dumps('timestamp': y, {'checkpoint_size': x, 'checkpoint_length': a, 'checkpoint_pause': b}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing another pair of `{}` around your dict, and a key name right where the ^ points.

Comment: Or, I guess more likely, put the `{` in front of `'timestamp'` instead of `'checkpoint_size'`.

Comment: @deceze: The `^` actually points to the `:`, not to the space in front of the `{` (can be seen by pasting the example into a Python session with `json` imported).

Comment: I tried that as well gives me the same sytax error {'timestamp': y, {'checkpoint_size': x, 'checkpoint_length': a, 'checkpoint_pause': b}}

Comment: @Imo: `json.dumps({'timestamp': y, 'checkpoint_size': x, 'checkpoint_length': a, 'checkpoint_pause': b}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One trick when you don't understand the syntax error in such case (an expression) is to simply break it down into subexpressions and take help from the interactive interpreter. Although you have to do some analysis yourself I think it's helpful.

Basically this is supposedly (you need to know your intention) a function call. A function call in python is one of [several forms](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), but in this case we can assume that it's of the form `f(a, b, ..., z)`, where the function and all arguments are expressions. So we check the subexpressions:

```
>>> json.dumps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'json' is not defined
```

That was not the error (that's another error that happens later during interpretation), and then each of the arguments:

```
>>> 'timestamp': y
File "<stdin>", line 1
   'timestamp': y
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There we have it, the first argument is not a valid expression, but if we put it in braces it would not generate syntax error. Then if you do that correction you will see that the whole expression is of correct syntax.